# What impact may I experience from disabling the Referrer header?

Tags: privacy

If I disable the Referrer header (possible [in Firefox](http://www.technipages.com/firefox-enable-disable-referrer), [Safari](https://superuser.com/q/739/133195), or [other browsers](https://superuser.com/q/756310/133195)), what impact may that have on my personal browsing experience?  Is it common for website functionality to rely on referrer headers?  I would suppose that for internal links, the pattern of requests already tells the web applications the same information.  What do I have to lose by disabling it?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not much. I expect that there are some sites that have security functionality that checks to ensure that the referrer is a page within the same site to prevent things like form submission from external sites.

You could always try it and see. It's not like it would be irreversible if it causes issues.